# New Asterisk 13 & 14 missing Application "Read()"

Tags: asterisk

I just upgraded from Asterisk 11 (Elastix) where this script was working to Asterisk 14. I am getting a slew of errors that are surprising. It appears problem is that there are some "default" applications missing.

the I have tried to uninstall and rebuilding both versions 13 and 14 using “make menuselect” making sure the options are selected for most applications are checked, including the Read application. When I finish, I can’t see it inside the Asterisk application list:

```
*CLI> core show applications
    -= Registered Asterisk Applications =-
                Answer: Answer a channel if ringing. 
            BackGround: Play an audio file while waiting for digits of an extension to go to. 
                Bridge: Bridge two channels. 
                  Busy: Indicate the Busy condition. 
  CallCompletionCancel: Cancel call completion service 
  CallCompletionRequest: Request call completion service for previous call 
            Congestion: Indicate the Congestion condition. 
            ExecIfTime: Conditional application execution based on the current time. 
                  Goto: Jump to a particular priority, extension, or context. 
                GotoIf: Conditional goto. 
            GotoIfTime: Conditional Goto based on the current time. 
                Hangup: Hang up the calling channel. 
             ImportVar: Import a variable from a channel into a new variable. 
            Incomplete: Returns AST_PBX_INCOMPLETE value. 
           MessageSend: Send a text message. 
                  MSet: Set channel variable(s) or function value(s). 
                  NoOp: Do Nothing (No Operation). 
            Proceeding: Indicate proceeding. 
              Progress: Indicate progress. 
        RaiseException: Handle an exceptional condition. 
               Ringing: Indicate ringing tone. 
              SayAlpha: Say Alpha. 
          SayAlphaCase: Say Alpha. 
             SayDigits: Say Digits. 
             SayNumber: Say Number. 
           SayPhonetic: Say Phonetic. 
                   Set: Set channel variable or function value. 
           SetAMAFlags: Set the AMA Flags. 
                  Wait: Waits for some time. 
             WaitExten: Waits for an extension to be entered. 
    -= 30 Applications Registered =-
```

The Elastix build I had would list over 150 applications doing the same thing. What can I do? I haven't seen any tutorials on how to enable specific applications other than using the "menuselect" method, any tips are appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE, After running `make samples` and `make config` and starting it as a service, it started working. I don't know if the difference was that before it wasn't starting as a service or what, but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are installed into /lib/asterisk/modules. Look for app_read.so. Try to load it in asterisk manually (module load app_read.so). Check asterisk log if it's not loaded.